# Can I use Intel SGX Debugger when I am not using Intel processor?

Tags: sgx

I am trying to learn how to develop secure application with Intel SGX and its SDK on Visual Studio 2019 but I am working on a computer with AMD processor (Ryzen 5 2600).

When I read couple of guides (mainly [this one](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/getting-started-with-sgx-sdk-for-windows.html)) on how to set up my VS, but when I get to the part where I need to change the debugger to "Intel SGX debugger" it is not available for me. I tried installing Visual Studio 2015 Community and Professional(trial), Visual Studio 2017 Community, VS 2019 Community and Professional because of this thread [here](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Software-Guard-Extensions/Problem-Cannot-find-SGX-Debugger-in-Visual-Studio/td-p/1126761)

Is the debugger only available if you are using SGX Enabled processor with the PSW software or am I doing something wrong.

I am using SGX SDK version 2.12.100.4 and I am not able to install the Intel SGX Platform Software because of the processor not being Intel SGX compatiable.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger is part of the SGX SDK package. It's called `sgx-gdb` and you can find it in the `bin` directory where you installed SGX SDK.

In my case it's in `/opt/intel/sgxsdk/bin/sgx-gdb`.